# how to auto expand when text is too long in Row in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am using this code to show text in flutter, this is my code:

```
Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      item.subName,
                      softWrap: true,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

sometimes the text `item.subName` is too long, how to make it auto expand or render in new line when the text overflow? I have tried to add this but still not work:

```
 softWrap: true,
```

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: If it's a single text widget that you want to wrap, you can either use Flexible or Expanded widgets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
new Container(
       child: Row(
         children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
               child: new Text("sample text"))
                ],
        ));
```

Comment: This is the best solution, since Expanded will force the text to take full row.

Answer (score 3):

```
Row(
         children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
               child: new Text("your text"))
                ],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: size.width * 0.4, // Choose a number that works for you
                        child: Text(
                          item.subName,
                          softWrap: true,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```